# Where can I reference all Unicode letters that JavaScript allows?

Tags: javascript

Chapter 2 of Definitive JavaScript states that an identifier must begin with

`$`, `_`, or a `letter` and be followed by the same + `digits`.

It also states that letters and digits included Unicode letters and digits.

Where can I get a list to reference all of these.

Interestingly, you can do things like:

```
var é
```

I was just looking for an exact list or description that is not overly technical.

This is for `ES-5`

Comment: A somewhat technical summary can be found in the standard itself: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6 - combine that with a resource that explains what characters fall in the mentioned Unicode categories. (Sidebar: do *not* get clever about using these fancy symbols - you will hate yourself when you have to revisit that code in two months. See [How to write unmaintainable code](http://thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html).)

Comment: Just to play around you can take a look at this [JavaScript variable name validator](http://mothereff.in/js-variables)

Answer (score 1):

The [ES5 spec explicitly lists which Unicode character categories are allowed in identifiers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).  Excluding Unicode escape sequences, here's a simplification of allowed identifiers:

So identifiers can start with:

- [Uppercase letter (Lu)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)
- [Lowercase letter (Ll)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)
- [Titlecase letter (Lt)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm)
- [Modifier letter (Lm)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm)
- [Other letter (Lo)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm)
- [Letter number (Nl)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm)
- `$`
- `_`

After that, zero or more the following characters are also allowed (in addition to all the characters listed above):

- [Non-spacing mark (Mn)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm)
- [Combining spacing mark (Mc)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm)
- [Decimal number (Nd)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)
- [Connector punctuation (Pc)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm)